# awx-tower connecting via proxy

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am trying to set up AWX Tower, to run playbooks via a jump server, I tried to follow few tutorials, like:
https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/2172
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/tipsandtricks.html#setting-up-a-jump-host-to-use-with-tower

**but it doesn't work:**

```
Host *
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null

Host jump-box
Hostname XXXXXXXXX
IdentityFile /var/lib/awx/.ssh/id_rsa_ansible

Host XXXXXXX
Proxycommand ssh -W ansible@XXXXXXXX nc %h:%p jump-box
```

I was also trying to set up with inventory proxy in awx web interface, but I am getting the same result, I have the newest awx and Ansible version installed, any suggestion would be very helpful.

I can ssh to other servers using the same config, it doesn't work only from AWX Web Interface

```
Error:
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

Comment: Hi adrian, welcome to SO. I appreciate your interest in obfuscating your hostnames, but maybe choose some concrete values like `example0` or `host1` because we can't decipher if those Xs are supposed to be the _same_ value or a different value. It sure does look like your config is circular, defining jump-box in terms of a host, which uses jump-box. You will also want to say how you know you can ssh to other servers using the same config, and include errors other than just the "connection closed." More details, better answers

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem, the problem was with awx user, looks like I had to add /bin/bash to the user, and restart all awx services.

Now ssh proxy works using Ansible from AWX Tower